# SSIS dynamic source and destination tables

Tags: ssis

I have some requirements as explained below:

1. I need to have a SSIS data data flow task,which will accept the input parameters as

   ```
   --SourceServer Connection String
   --DestinationServer Connection String
   --Source Table Name
   --Destination Table Name
   ```
2. Then It should do the column mapping of source and destination tables dynamically at run time.
3. The source and destination tables schema would be same always.
4. I want to call this package by passing the above parameters from C#.net.
5. One main thing is here I will have to pass different sets of source and destination tables.

Comment: Guess you have to use a script component as source and destination task. It keeps you dynamic and should meet your recommendations. Have a look at this for ex. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx

Answer (score 0):

just answered this on a previous question. You cant loop through tables and dinamically map columns on your source and destinations components. You would need one set of Source -> Ddestination per table.

If that's not feasible, you may want to lokk at the [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create SSIS Packages parameters. Set web.config file for passing that parameters.

First you deploy the package in SQL Server.
Create one job for execute the package.
Create one sp using SQL Server.
& execute the job.
using sp_start_job.

I think it solve ur problem.